# How to enter manually a key-value to seaborn jointplot stat_func?

Tags: python, seaborn

i want to display some parameter on a seaborn jointplot.

Lets say `apples=5` just like `pearson=.3`

I am not interested in the default option. so i generated the graph with the following line of code:

```
sns.jointplot(sp.time, mn, color="#4CB391", stat_func=None)
```

The Documentation states:

```
stat_func : callable or None, optional
Function used to calculate a statistic about the relationship and annotate the plot. 
Should map x and y either to a single value or to a (value, p) tuple. 
Set to None if you don’t want to annotate the plot.
```

could someone help fill in the `stat_func` properly do display a key-value pair of my choosing?

Thank you.

The plot is [image]

Comment: Don't use `stat_func` if you're not computing a statistic from the data, just add text to the axes.

Comment: what if i were to compute a statistic from scipy.stats. such as linear regression.

Answer (score 1):

You can create you own function that takes two input parameters (x and y from the call to `sns.jointplot()`) and returns a value or a tuple of two values. If you just want to display arbitrary text, it is better to use `ax.text()` as indicated in @mwaskom's comment to your question. But if you are calculating something from a function of your own, you could do:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

def apples(x, y):
    # Actual calculations go here
    return 5

sns.jointplot('tip', 'total_bill', data=tips, stat_func=apples)
```

[image]

If `apples()` returned two values in a tuple (e.g. `return (5, 0.3)`), the second value would represent `p` and the resulting text annotation would be `apples = 5; p = 0.3`.

You could compute any statistics like this, as long as the return format is a single value or a `(value, p)` tuple. If you want to use `scipy.stats.kendalltau` for example, you would do

```
from scipy import stats
sns.jointplot('tip', 'total_bill', data=tips, stat_func=stats.kendalltau)
```

[image]